# On convex functions which are non constant on every segment

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, convexity, calculus-of-variations

I have been studying for the last few weeks the paper [Dirichlet problem for demi-coercive functionals](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0362546X86901458) by Anzellotti, Buttazzo and Dal Maso. In this work the authors introduced and studied the variational properties of a class of funtionals - that they call *demi-coercive*. The definition is the following:

> **Definition.** A function $f\colon \mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R$ is *demi-coercive (DC)* if there are $a>0, b \ge 0$ and $\gamma \in \mathbb R^N$ such that 
>   $$
> a|x| \le f(x) + \langle \gamma, x \rangle + b
> $$
>   for any $x \in \mathbb R^N$.

Among other interesting characterizations (see Thm. 2.4 of the above paper) one is of particular interest to me as of today. Namely:

> **Prop. (A)** A convex, lower semicontinuous function $f\colon \mathbb R^N \to [0,+\infty)$ is DC iff there are no straight lines along which $f$ is constant.

I am interested into this proposition for the following reason: I need to modify the above property by considering the more restrictive variant:

> **Prop/Def. (B)** A convex, lower semicontinuous function $f\colon \mathbb R^N \to [0,+\infty)$ is **?** iff there are no non-trivial straight *segments* along which $f$ is finite and constant.

Indeed, in Prop. (A) the equivalence relies really on the fact that there are no *lines* on which $f$ is constant (so it can be constant on a bounded segment, even on half lines).

On the contrary, in Prop. (B) I want to rule out the possibility that $f$ is constant even on a segment.

**Question(s).**

1. What should I put in place of (?) ? I would like to know if Prop/Def (B) has ever been considered in literature (do these functions have a name?).
2. I would also like to see if there are equivalent characterizations: in particular, is it possible to say something relating to (B) in terms of the level sets of $f$ and their extreme points?

Notice that easy examples of (1-homogeneous) functions satisfying A but not B are the $\ell^1$ or $\ell^\infty$ norm on $\mathbb R^N$, as one can directly check. Notice that for all others $p \in (1,+\infty)$ the $p$-norm does satisfy both A and B.

Comment: To the down-voter: could you please leave a constructive feedback so that I can modify my question accordingly? Thanks.

Comment: I do not know the answer, but if there is no sexy name for this class, it could be called in a descriptive manner "a class of convex functions with strictly convex level sets". This is no shorter than "convex and not constant on any segment", though.

Answer (score 1):

**strictly convex** means: convex and not affine on any non-trivial line segment.

[LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function)

So **B** is something between convex and strictly convex.

Comment: Yes exactly, the point is indeed to put precisely how B is "between" strictly convex and convex. As for A, if I am not wrong, it should hold something like this: A is the "closure" (in a suitable sense) of strictly convex functions (see e.g. [this thesis](http://math.sns.it/media/doc/paper/1256/tesidottorato.pdf), Thm. 3.5). I would like to get something like this for B... Thanks for your answer.